# React - useState not updating when used inside of useEffect

Tags: react-hooks

In my project, I want to save all `console.log`'s in an array.
I created a simple example that represents what I am trying to do.

1. A simple button that when pressed - logs to the console.
2. An array for all logged messages
3. An `useEffect` hook that overrides the `console.log` function.

However, the array doesn't get bigger than 1 item.

The code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myLogs, setMyLogs] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    var log = console.log;
    console.log("from useEffect");
    console.log = function () {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      log.apply(this, args);
      setMyLogs({ ...myLogs, ...args });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log("clicked :)")}>Click to Log</button>
      <p>{myLogs.toString()}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactconsolelogtovariable-b20e6?file=/src/App.tsx)

I tried adding `myLogs` as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook thinking it might help but it just created an infinite loop. (This part I understand)

Comment: As an aside, it seems to me that overriding the global console.log function to set state in a React component is a not so great idea. Is there a particular reason you've set out to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting log as the object it should be an array. and correct way of doing this is below

```
setMyLogs((prev) => [ ...prev, ...args ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that of a stale enclosure of initial `myLogs` state and also that of mutating the state invariant from `array` to `object` type.

Use a functional state update to correctly update from any previous state and not the state value closed over in callback scope. Maintain the array state invariant.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const log = console.log;
  console.log("from useEffect");
  console.log = function () {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    log.apply(this, args);
    setMyLogs(myLogs => [...myLogs, args]);
    // or [...myLogs, ...args] if you want all the log args flattened
  };
}, []);
```